# Font identification from BNHA again

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

I got help the last time I posted here so hopefully you guys can help me again!
[image]

The closest font i've found for this particular one is either Iwata UD Gothic Heavy Display or Kozuka Gothic Heavy however neither include the little legs on 谷

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first pic: [ヒラギノ角ゴ](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/1813) (A MacOS builtin font; though not sure if the specific weight is)

[image] (example in weight W8)

The second pic: Almost [ナウ](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/1690)

[image] (GE)

[image] (GU)

"Almost" because the actual glyph り apparently has a small seam in the middle between two strokes, unlike the original font connected. It'd be a very outstanding feature for such kind of fonts, but I don't think I have ever seen one with this shape. Perhaps the author has something particular that requires the design adjustment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Devilmusic if it helped, can you please mark it accepted.